# AngularJS: Ng-repeat in groups of n elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a set of data like this:

```
$scope.items = [
    { model:"A", price: 100, quantity: 30}, 
    { model:"B", price: 90, quantity: 20 },
    { model:"C", price: 80, quantity: 200 }, 
    { model:"D", price: 70, quantity: 20 },
    { model:"E", price: 60, quantity: 100 }, 
    { model:"F", price: 50, quantity: 70 },
    { model:"G", price: 40, quantity: 230 }, 
    { model:"H", price: 30, quantity: 50 }
];
```

I would like use ng-repeat but then making groups of 4, so the output would be something like this

```
<ul>
    <li> model:"A", price: 100, quantity: 30</li>
    <li> model:"B", price: 90, quantity: 20</li>
    <li> model:"C", price: 80, quantity: 200</li>
    <li> model:"D", price: 70, quantity: 20</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li> model:"E", price: 60, quantity: 100</li>
    <li> model:"F", price: 50, quantity: 70</li>
    <li> model:"G", price: 40, quantity: 230</li>
    <li> model:"H", price: 30, quantity: 50</li>
</ul>
```

And then be able to sort it by price and quantity. I've tried with

```
<li ng-repeat="x in items.slice(0,4)">
```

but then I just can sort within each group. Also, I am looking for a solution that could work for any given number of elements. This proposed solution [Group ng-repeat items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285351/group-ng-repeat-items) just work when you know in advance the number of items that you will have.

PS: I'm trying not to use the pagination directive as it gives me a conflict with other script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the logic in the controller, so you want an array of arrays. In lodash `$scope.items = _.chunk(items, 4)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group ng-repeat items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285351/group-ng-repeat-items)

Comment: if you want them all to sort why do you need separate `<ul>` for each group and not just put them all in one?

Comment: @chalietfl in order to fit it in a slider that shows element 4 by 4. If I put them together in one <ul>, then the layout breaks

Comment: @TaylorCampbell: The solution you proposed just work if you know in advance the total number of elements.

Comment: Isn't there a filter `sortBy`? Or would that not work for this.

Comment: really not clear what the sorting issue is then

Comment: @charlietfl if I use slice I create groups that are "isolated", so if I sort f.ex, in quantity, there would be two groups sorted from max to min, but what I need is to first make the sorting and then the groups (so in the first group there would be those 4 with higher quantity, and in the second those 4 with lower).

Comment: so you do that sort in controller before passing to view. Can't expect the view to do everything for you, often have to massage data first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

created an example using lodash (_.sortBy and _.chunk), it's not the best but better than nothing:

https://jsfiddle.net/1LLf7gz6/

you can also shorten by removing:

```
$scope.itemssorted = _.sortBy($scope.items, 'price');
```

and add this:

```
$scope.itemschunk = _.chunk(_.sortBy($scope.items, 'price'), 4);
```

jsfiddle (new): https://jsfiddle.net/py5hs1yj/

jsfiddle with sort buttons example: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldcpx35w/

**Documentation:**

._sortBy() -> https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy
._chunk() -> https://lodash.com/docs#chunk

**jsfiddle code:**

**Script:**

```
var app = angular.module('anExample', []);

app.controller('theController', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.test = 'this is a test';

  $scope.items = [
    { model:"A", price: 100, quantity: 30}, 
    { model:"B", price: 90, quantity: 20 },
    { model:"C", price: 80, quantity: 200 }, 
    { model:"D", price: 70, quantity: 20 },
    { model:"E", price: 60, quantity: 100 }, 
    { model:"F", price: 50, quantity: 70 },
    { model:"G", price: 40, quantity: 230 }, 
    { model:"H", price: 30, quantity: 50 }
    ];

  //$scope.itemssorted = _.sortBy($scope.items, 'price');
  //example: reverse array
  //$scope.itemssorted = _.sortBy($scope.items, 'price').reverse();

  $scope.itemschunk = _.chunk(_.sortBy($scope.items, 'price'), 4);


  console.log("items: ", $scope.items);
  console.log("items chunked: ", $scope.itemschunk);
  //console.log("items sorted: ", $scope.itemssorted);

}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="anExample" ng-controller="theController">

    Hello, {{test}}!
    <ul ng-repeat="group in itemschunk">
      <li ng-repeat="items in group"> Model: {{items.model}}, price: {{items.price}}, quantity: {{items.quantity}}</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**Result:**

```
Hello, this is a test!

Model: H, price: 30, quantity: 50
Model: G, price: 40, quantity: 230
Model: F, price: 50, quantity: 70
Model: E, price: 60, quantity: 100

Model: D, price: 70, quantity: 20
Model: C, price: 80, quantity: 200
Model: B, price: 90, quantity: 20
Model: A, price: 100, quantity: 30
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works perfect when setting manually either the "price" or "quantity" variable manually, but I would need to be able to be able to switch from different orderings (price high to low, qty high to low, price low to high, qty low to high) and then choose the desired order in a dropdown menu.

Comment: Here is an example with buttons to sort. I don't have time to complete (asc/des), but you should manage that by my examples. You can allways ask if you have a problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldcpx35w/

Comment: I changed _.sortby for _.order by (in order to do it ascending or descending). And now it works perfect. I mark the answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First group your data in the controller, Then you can use nested `ng-repeat` in your view and apply your `orderBy` clause.

**Controller**

```
$scope.items = [
  { model:"A", price: 100, quantity: 30}, 
  { model:"B", price: 90, quantity: 20 },
  { model:"C", price: 80, quantity: 200 }, 
  { model:"D", price: 70, quantity: 20 },
  { model:"E", price: 60, quantity: 100 }, 
  { model:"F", price: 50, quantity: 70 },
  { model:"G", price: 40, quantity: 230 }, 
  { model:"H", price: 30, quantity: 50 }
];

$scope.groupedItems = _groupItems($scope.items, 4, 'price');

function _groupItems (items, size, sort) {
  var grouped = [],
      index = 0;

  if (angular.isDefined(sort)) {
    $filter('orderBy')(items, sort);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (angular.isUndefined(grouped[index])) {
      grouped[index] = [];
    }

    grouped[index].push(items[i]);

    if ((i+1) % size === 0) {
      index++;
    }
  }

  return grouped;
}
```

**View**

```
<ul ng-repeat="group in groupedItems">
  <li ng-repeat="item in group | orderBy:'price'">
    model:"{{item.model}}", price:{{item.price}}, quantity: {{item.quantity}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with this solution is that when ordering, it just orders within the groups of 4 So if I order by quantity, I will get 2 groups of [200, 30, 20, 20] and [230, 100, 70, 50], instead of 2 groups of [230, 200, 100, 70] and [50, 30, 20, 20] that would be the desired outcome.

Comment: I updated my answer to include an optional sort attribute using the angular $filter service before grouping items

Comment: I marked the other one as correct as it uses lodash library, and it is easier to mantain, but this one works perfect as well. Thanks!