# How to edit angular variables inside the markup?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm really new to all these so I don't know if I could be able to explain my problem...

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLvwhyxe/)

(I don't know why it doesn't work...I'm really very new to angular and ionic)

I want to create a ng-repeat that displays all my items that are active (active=true) but also,I want to open a row every 5 items and insert the next five items, and so...till the loop ends.

I was thinking in using `$index%5=0` to do that, but it doesn't filter the active=true items...how do I fix this?

PS: all of this without editing the original array, of course...

Comment: did you include angular library in the fiddle?...because it is not present in external resources

Comment: please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441885/angularjs-ng-repeat-in-groups-of-n-elements

Comment: Yup, it doesn't work either...But in my project works, the fiddle is not the problem here anyway ^^U

Comment: Thank you, lodash was the big answer to my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

try like this. use `ng-src` instead of `src` and also you should create `equipment` object at first.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function DetailCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.caravan = {equipment:[]};
 $scope.caravan.equipment = [
  {name: 'ABS (Sistema Antibloqueo)', active:true, image:"http://www.iearobotics.com/wiki/images/0/06/Icono_ok.png"},
  {name: 'Aire Acondicionado en Cabina', active:true, image:"http://www.iearobotics.com/wiki/images/0/06/Icono_ok.png"},
  {name: 'Alarma Antirrobo', active:true, image:"http://www.iearobotics.com/wiki/images/0/06/Icono_ok.png"},
  {name: 'Antena Parabólica', active:false, image:"http://www.iearobotics.com/wiki/images/0/06/Icono_ok.png"},
  {name: 'ASR (Sistema de Tracción Antideslizante', active:false, image:"http://www.iearobotics.com/wiki/images/0/06/Icono_ok.png"},
  {name: 'Calefacción en habitáculo', active:true, image:"http://www.iearobotics.com/wiki/images/0/06/Icono_ok.png"},
      {name: 'ABS (Sistema Antibloqueo)', active:true, image:"http://www.iearobotics.com/wiki/images/0/06/Icono_ok.png"},
  {name: 'Aire Acondicionado en Cabina', active:true, image:"http://www.iearobotics.com/wiki/images/0/06/Icono_ok.png"},
  {name: 'Alarma Antirrobo', active:true, image:"http://www.iearobotics.com/wiki/images/0/06/Icono_ok.png"},
  {name: 'Antena Parabólica', active:false, image:"http://www.iearobotics.com/wiki/images/0/06/Icono_ok.png"},
  {name: 'ASR (Sistema de Tracción Antideslizante', active:false, image:"http://www.iearobotics.com/wiki/images/0/06/Icono_ok.png"},
  {name: 'Calefacción en habitáculo', active:true, image:"http://www.iearobotics.com/wiki/images/0/06/Icono_ok.png"}
  ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" class="caravan-equipment" ng-controller="DetailCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <h3>EQUIPMENT</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="equipment in caravan.equipment">
      <div ng-if="equipment.active" class="col col-20 icon-equipment">
        <img ng-src="{{equipment.image}}"/>
      </div>
     
      <br ng-if="$index %6 == 0 && $index != 0">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you see my answer?

Comment: Yeah, I copied your code in fiddle and it doesn't work ^^U...Again, in my project works fine, that's not the problem...

Comment: NO . not problem. may be in fiddle angular files not loaded.